# How to display man page with a specific path?

Tags: command-line, path, aix, man

There are some binaries and corresponding man pages on the IBM AIX system I am working with (/some/path/bin and /some/path/man), but neither bin nor man directory are in my `$PATH` or `$MANPATH` . I would like to view the specific man page. How do I display the man page, given I know its locaction, i.e. /some/path/man/my_man.5?

If I run `man /some/path/man/my_man.5` I get `Manual entry for /some/path/man/my_man.5 not found or not installed.`

I have tried to add the path /some/path/man to my `$MANPATH` environment variable, but then when I do `man my_man.5` I get the usual man screen, but it displays only the header of the whole man page, i.e. Page 1, while if I `vim /some/path/man/my_man.5` I see the whole text.

The issue seems to manifest itself on AIX system (where as I understand lot of tools are not GNU), cause if I do `man /some/path/man/my_man.5` on Linux system I do get the expected man screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the MANPATH variable for this call to `man` - i.e.:

```
 MANPATH=/usr/local/share/man man gcc
```

Note that a variable assignment before a command does *not* change the current environment - only the called command get's a modified environment.

EDIT:

If the manpage is not displayed properly, you may have to check whether `nroff` and friends are installed properly on the system. Could be that a specific `roff` macro package is missing - but this is hard to tell from this side of the screen.

Another explanation would be that the man page in question uses GNU-roff extensions not supported by standard `roff`.

EDIT 2:

To test whether installed `nroff` is able to cope with the provided man page:

```
 nroff -man -Tascii youmanpage.man > yourmanpage.txt
```

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your answer, could you explain in more detail? As I have described in my question I have already tried to add /some/path/man to my $MANPATH, but it did not help. Are you suggesting to try the same thing here?

Comment: I do `nroff -man -Tascii youmanpage.man > yourmanpage.txt` I get a formatted file similar to the one man shows me if I add the /some/path/man to the MANPATH. So I guess it is quite credible, that the hgrc.5 man page I try to display is prepared with GNU tools and is not compatible with the tools installed on this AIX machine.